# Return to development mode running vue-cli Webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I've been unable to find an answer to this seemingly simple problem:

I'm running a [vue-cli webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) development environment.

Yesterday I wanted to upload my project in-the-making and ran "npm run build". The project isn't done, and I'd like to keep working on it without building it each time I want to verify a change.

Can I restore the development environment without cloning my new files into a fresh vue-cli directory?

I've tried renaming the dist-folder and running "npm run dev", but it produces a 404 on build.js